# CVS Date columns comes as time(?) format - SQL server import issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, csv

I have a CSV file here that one of the columns is supposed to be a date but it is stored as if date, I tried importing it to SQL server and set it to date but it says it cannot be converted. Also tried on excel converting the to date format but also didn't work. Anyone know how to resolve this so I can convert/import this column as DATE and not this time format?

[image]

```
PatientId   CreatedDate
365         43:29.1
189         12:01.4
42          05:42.7
2426        33:02.6
61          05:18.7
2442        16:10.8
15          32:59.3
8           41:16.8
127         26:47.9
```

Comment: Rather than a [screen]shot, the actual contents in a code fence (`\`\`\``) would be infinitely better.

Comment: @ScottCraner a "shot"? Nooooo.

Comment: please explain how `43:29.1` is a date?

Comment: Hi all, apologize for the confusion I am very new to this, I have updated the post with the data. Thank you all so much for the input and time!!!

Comment: @ScottCraner it is suppose to be a DATE, but for some reason it is in this weird format and I simply can't figure out how to convert/import to database in its proper date format.

Comment: Then the issue is with what created the CSV.  If you cannot tell us the rules for conversion there is probably no way we can help.

Comment: It looks like an initial Excel format issue where the column is then imported as text. Try reformatting the Excel column to a date format and/or modify the import method. (I have suffered this in the past)

Comment: One thing, what you are showing us, is that after you opened and saved in Excel?  If so, we need to see the original csv, before trying to open in Excel.

Comment: @ScottCraner No this is copied straight out of the CSV file, the file was sent to me from a vendor and I didn't make any changes to it. I tried saving it as xlsx and change the format but it simply won't do it

Comment: Then you will need to get with the vendor to try and make sense how that value relates to a date.  If you cannot make sense of it how will excel?  That does not fit any date format that excel will recognize.  It looks like a time in the `[mm]:ss.0` format Which is why Excel formats it as such.

Comment: That doesn't look like a CSV either, but a fixed width file, based on your sample.